# Finite automata to regular expression via state removal

Tags: regex, finite-automata, automata

I am trying to convert this finite automata to a regular expression using state removal. When removing a state, I know that I should look at all outgoing and incoming transitions, and make sure sure that all paths though the soon to be removed state are preserved. However, I still find this entire concept a bit confusing. I have attached an image of a practice problem I've attempted, and I was wondering if it was correct. I would also appreciate any tips for tackling these types of problems.

[image: fa-to-regex]

Comment: I have a question, at step1) we cannot reach B just by 0 but at step 2) we  can reach B just by 0. can you explain about adding +0 at your expression in 0*1+0 ?

Comment: Yeah that was the confusing part for me. There is a transition from C to A with an input of 0.. I wasn't sure where else to incorporate it so I put the +0 there. Perhaps I should remove it all together...because wouldn't 0*1 work on its own?

Comment: post your code not images.

Comment: This is a good question and sorry I cannot solve it right now, on my way. but your final regx is accepting '001' but your original is not accepting it. Am I right?

Comment: Rebin: yes, I see that. I am trying to see if I can fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a correct solution. (by the way I dont know if we can delete A at first step)
[image]